# Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mocha.js, supertest

I wrote the testing code and it worked fine but after I added other routes that didn't relate to the current code, the code became corrupted, especially at this point:

> 1)  "before each" hook for "should create new todo":
>        Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test`.

```
const todos = [{
  _id: new ObjectID(),
  text: 'first test todo',
  completed: false,
  completedAt: null
}, {
  _id: new ObjectID(),
  text: 'second test todo',
  completed: true,
  completedAt: 333
}];


beforeEach((done) => {
  Todo.remove({}).then(() => {
    return Todo.insertMany(todos);
  }).then((docs) => {
    done();
  });
})
describe('post /todo', () => {
  it('should create new todo', (done) => {
    let text = 'here from supertest';
    request(app)
      .post('/todos')
      .send({
        text
      })
      .expect(200)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body.text).toBe(text);

      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }

        Todo.find({
            text
          }).then((res) => {
            expect(res.length).toBe(1);
            expect(res[0].text).toBe(text);
            done();
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            done(e);
          });
      });
  });
});
```

The whole project is [in this github libary called TestMongo](https://github.com/mohamedshedo/TestMongo), where you can check the last two commits that have the issues with testing that I face but when you try it by postman it works fine.  When one reverts to the third commit from the end, the testing works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably we need to increase the timeout of test to bigger number

```
beforeEach(function(done) { // dont use arrow function to use this.timeout
  this.timeout(5000); // override default 2000 ms

  Todo.remove({}).then(() => {
    return Todo.insertMany(todos);
  }).then((docs) => {
    done();
  });
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you it works.I want to understand why? It behaves as like this after I just put a schema for another model that isn't included in this testing at all. as it works so well if I deleted this schema?!

Comment: perhaps you can try to set some breakpoint and debugging the code when the test is running before and after adding that schema to see the differences. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oFKNL7vYV8